# Safely saving data via an API in a HTML5/WebGL Game

Tags: php, javascript, html, three.js, webgl

I am creating a HTML5/WebGL based game and am getting a little stuck when thinking about saving game data to the server.

I need to save the data with out a page load. So the obvious choice is to use a AJAX call to my servers Restful API.
Obviously this presents a few issues. Mainly spoof requests. Using AJAX calls will mean the request is being made client side, allowing "bad" users to send their own request to the server altering the data to benefit themselves.

I first thought to secure the server using sessions. On the initial page load, store a session allowing access to the API. Though I am sure sessions can be spoofed.

How could I best achieve saving game data to a server safely?

Comment: this is part of the huge gap that html5 has, there is no security, since its all client side, and its all open.  The only thing to do really, is try to verify the data any way you can on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could expand on this simple example;

```
<?php
$secret = "test123";
$time = time();
$code = md5($secret.$time);
```

The secret and time are combined and hashed together.  The resulting code and the time are sent to the server;

```
http://www.domain.com?TIME=1362668370&CODE=cdade9f3df6a8cb9b17c736b96c64133
```

The server can then hash the secret and received time value and compare that with the received CODE.